# How do I correctly add a snapshot listener to a Firebase Firestore document reference in Java?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following the Java (Android) documentation to a tee for realtime updates however I'm getting error: `EventListener takes no type parameters`.

I removed `<DocumentSnapshot>`  but that just caused further errors.

Here is the code block from the documentation:

```
final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
            return;
        }
        if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Current data: " + snapshot.getData());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null");
        }
    }
});
```

The above sample is identical to Google's published documentation. Here is the documentation I am following:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably imported the wrong EventListner.  Make sure your import is like this:

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
```

And **not**, for example, like this:

```
import java.util.EventListener;
```

Comment: That appeared to be the issue. Looks like Android Studio auto imported the wrong package. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Thanks for answering Doug, cool to see you on here answering questions. I've seen you in many Firebase videos.